# Java HashMap automatic value replicating issue

Tags: java, hashmap

Whenever I start setting my HashMaps, the values get replicated. I believe that it is  some Java rule that I don't understand when initilizing the HashMap. Below is my DTO of my HashMaps.

```
public class ClientsByMonth {
private int pax;
private int folios;
private int totalStays;
private HashMap<String, Integer> byCountry = new HashMap<>();   
private HashMap<String, Integer> groups = new HashMap<>();
```

Below is where I am initializing HashMaps.

```
public class CMBSetter{ 
private HashMap<Integer, Clients> clients = new HashMap<>();
private HashMap<Integer, ClientsByMonth> clientsBM = new HashMap<>();

 public void preSetterList(){
    // ----     --- COUNTRY SETTER ---      ----
     HashMap<String, Integer> byCountry = new HashMap();

    String[] countrys = {"GB ", "PT ", "ES ", "BE ", "IE ", "FR ", "DE ", "CH ", "IR ", "NL ", "   ", "Others"};
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        byCountry.put(countrys[i], 0);

    }
    //  ****    *** GROUPS SETTER ***   ****
    HashMap<String, Integer> groups = new HashMap<>();
    Collection<String> keysGroup = groups.keySet();
    groups.put("test", 0);

    Collection<Integer> keysCleint = clients.keySet();

    for(Integer keyC: keysCleint){            
        String groupNameClient = clients.get(keyC).getGroupName();
        boolean namefound = false;

        for(String keyG: keysGroup){
            if(groupNameClient.equals(keyG)){
                namefound = true;
            }  
        }
        if(!namefound){
        groups.put(groupNameClient, 0);
        } 
    }
     //  _)_)_)_   )_)_  DTO SETTER )_)_   _)_)_)_

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){

        clientsBM.put(i, new ClientsByMonth());
        clientsBM.get(i).setByCountry(byCountry[i]);
        clientsBM.get(i).setGroups(groups);
    }
}
```

**My question:**

How do I initialize the HashMaps so the values are not replicated when I set them?
How do I initialize the HashMaps without this issue occurring?

**What I am trying to do:**

I.E.2- I want to the array of countries to fill in my byCountry HashMap in my DTO ClientsByMonth. Such as ("GB", 0) and ("IR", 0) and ("DE", 0).

I.E.2- I want the Groups setter to iterate through the clients HashMap and store the all the names that exist under GroupName() in my new HashMap which has a DTO object with a HashMap. Values such as HashMap groups(BIT, 0) and (BOOKING, 0) and (TRVLFAR, 0).

I am first creating (presetting) all the "labels/keys" in the HashMap because I am always getting Null pointer errors when I try to iterate over hash map that is empty.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? `HashMap<String, Integer>[] byCountry` creates an array of hash maps, each of which get to hold 1 country. Are you trying to initialize this: `private HashMap<String, Integer> byCountry = new HashMap<>(); ` in the code I pasted above?

Comment: An array of Hashmaps - how bizzare

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I edited the post with the answers to the comments.

Comment: why dont you hardcode to fill in the HashMaps? also why are you setting all of your byCountry hashmap values to 0?

Comment: I only have a guess at what your program is suppose to be doing and I feel you are overcomplicating it. So what is the purpose of using so many Hasmaps? Is the data so big and have to be accessed so fast? A booking system is usually using a Database or an ObjectOriented solution to solve this.

Comment: f the first box of code is in the same class as the methods in the next box, then you are creating antoerh two HashMap objects byCounty and group in your function scope

Comment: @ local plutonium No they are both two different classes. I thought Harcoding is bad coding. Like I said on the last lines, If I don't I can't start iterating over a hashMap that is empty in order to fill it in.

Comment: One beginner's pitfall in doing something like `clientsBM.get(i).setGroups(groups);` is that you now are sharing the object held by `groups`. Any change afterwards to `groups` will hold for all `clientsBM.get(i)`. _Honestly said I did not try to understand the code as it seems overly complex._

Comment: @Joop Eggen - yes I was hoping someone would say that. So how do I overcome this?

Comment: Start with the entire abstract data model, with sample data. It seems you are having raw data and want to have derived data by month, by ... . If you present that (and show your own efforts, which you already did), it is more likely to receive an answer. Now everything is a map; something for a Perl programmer.

Comment: _"I am first creating (presetting) all the "labels/keys" in the HashMap because I am always getting Null pointer errors when I try to iterate over hash map that is empty"._
Use an Iterator from the keySet to avoid hitting null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
from the comments

**Joop Eggen**

> One beginner's pitfall in doing something like
>   clientsBM.get(i).setGroups(groups); is that you now are sharing the
>   object held by groups. Any change afterwards to groups will hold for
>   all clientsBM.get(i)

**heniv181**

> "I am first creating (presetting) all the "labels/keys" in the HashMap
>   because I am always getting Null pointer errors when I try to iterate
>   over hash map that is empty". Use an Iterator from the keySet to avoid
>   hitting null.